# How to create a bubble sort of a double-linked list for Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have been implementing a bubble sort for a doubly linked list:

```
def sort2(list)  #bubble sort
  for i in 0...list.length
    for j in 0...list.length-1-i
      if list.get(j+1)<list.get(j)
        list.swap(j+1, j)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't have any idea how implement a bucket-sort. We can only use methods like:

- `get(i)` - which return value of `i` element
- `swap(i, j)` - which swaps two elements
- `length(list)` - return length of list

This is the code for `get`, `swap` and `length`:

```
def swap(i,j)  
  if i > j
    i, j = j, i
  elsif j == i
    return
  end
  tmp = nil        
  list = @ListE.next  #first element
  for it in 0...j
    if i == it
      tmp = list
    end
    list = list.next
  end
  tmp.v, list.v = list.v, tmp.v
end

def get(i)
  a = @ListE
  while i>0
    a = a.next
    i-=1
  end
  return a.next.v
end

def length()
  list = @ListE.next
  length_of_list = 0
  while list.v != nil
    length_of_list += 1
    list = list.next
  end
  return length_of_list
end
```

This is my attempt at an insertion sort:

```
def sort3(list)  #insertion sort
  for i in 1...list.length
    j = i
    while j > 0 and list.get(j-1) > list.get(j)
      list.swap(j-1, i)
      j -= 1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There is a ton of code missing here, like what `get` and `swap` do.

Comment: Keep in mind Ruby hardly ever uses `for` directly. It's preferable to do `list.each` or `list.each_with_index`.

Comment: Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)".

Comment: Added code of methods and my try of insertion sort

Comment: Don't use `and`, use `&&` instead. You have objects in your code that aren't defined. Don't do that. Again, see "[mcve]". We need verifiable code, which means code that runs, but doesn't do what you want. Syntax errors are a reason we close questions.